# How to disable screen going blank/off in X11?

Tags: x11, gnu-screen, xset

Is there a simple way of disabling this? I don't have any power saving constraints currently, as my desktop is always plugged in and I don't mind having it running forever. All of the explanations on `xset` I've found so far are so long and convoluted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest way is to:

```bsh
xset -dpms
xset s off # if you also want to disable the screen saver
```

You can put that inside your `.xinitrc` so, every time you log in, that's executed. There are more efficient ways of making this programmatic though, one of them is mentioned at the end of one of [Brodie Robertson's videos](https://youtu.be/0zqOiy9LuBw?list=PLMYMhzMuvitTjUeqRXebVJ2Ol_sRktdjj&t=648).

> DPMS stands for [Display Power Management Signaling](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling).

You could also customize your `Standby`, `Suspend` and `Off` times with something like:

```bsh
xset dpms 200 300 400
```